# Debugging Windows kernel on a Microsoft Azure platform virtual machine

Tags: windows, azure, kernel, windbg

I want to connect WinDbg to the Windows Server kernel running on a Microsoft Azure platform VM to debug some drivers. I tried to follow the instructions on msdn to connect the debugger over the network, but it seems that requires that the target machine and the host are locate in one local network. What are the options, is it possible to do it at all?

I tried:
[Setting Up Network Debugging of a Virtual Machine - KDNET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-network-debugging-of-a-virtual-machine-host)

Comment: You should be able to download the VM image locally and then start debugging in your local network. It makes no sense to debug over the internet.

Comment: @LexLi This turned out to be a good solution for me when I don't have the ability to deploy a VM locally. This is also useful when I need to test the work on different editions of the operating system or investigate their kernel.

Comment: If both [security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/security-during-remote-debugging) and network latency/instability are not your concerns, then yes you can stick to that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. It was necessary to add a new rule for the port used by the kernel debugger. This is done in the virtual machine settings in the "Network" section.